# Why can't Go cast back an interface that implements a generic?

Tags: go, generics, interface, casting

I'm trying to explore the type system of Go, having fun programming a small side project, but I end up on a weird case.

When an `interface` that can take a type, in which use it for a function, a `struct` that implement that `interface` which is contained into a map of the `interface`, when retrieved I can't cast it back to the implementation. Why? How? What's wrong?

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
)

type State struct {
    Data string
}

type InterfaceFuncs[T any] interface {
    Init(ctx context.Context,
        stateGetter func() T,
        stateMutator func(mutateFunc func(T) T)) error
}

type ConfigWrap[T any] struct {
    InterFuncs InterfaceFuncs[T]
}

type Controller[T any] struct {
    mapinterfaces map[string]ConfigWrap[T]
}

func New[T any](initialState T) *Controller[T] {
    return &Controller[T]{
        mapinterfaces: make(map[string]ConfigWrap[T]),
    }
}

func (c *Controller[T]) RegisterFuncs(pid string, config ConfigWrap[T]) error {
    c.mapinterfaces[pid] = config
    return nil
}

func (c *Controller[T]) InterFuncs(pid string) (*InterfaceFuncs[T], error) {

    var pp ConfigWrap[T]
    var exists bool

    if pp, exists = c.mapinterfaces[pid]; exists {
        return &pp.InterFuncs, nil
    }

    return nil, fmt.Errorf("InterFuncs not found")
}

func main() {

    ctrl := New[State](State{})

    ctrl.RegisterFuncs("something", ConfigWrap[State]{
        InterFuncs: &ImpltProcFuncs{
            Data: "get me back!!!!",
        },
    })

    // why can't we cast it back to ImpltProcFuncs
    getback, _ := ctrl.InterFuncs("something")

    // I tried to put it as interface but doesn't works either
    //// doesn't work
    switch value := any(getback).(type) {
    case ImpltProcFuncs:
        fmt.Println("working", value)
    default:
        fmt.Println("nothing")
    }

    //// doesn't work
    // tryme := any(getback).(ImpltProcFuncs) // panic: interface conversion: interface {} is *main.InterfaceFuncs[main.State], not main.ImpltProcFuncs
    // fmt.Println("please", tryme.Data)

    //// doesn't work
    // tryme := getback.(ImpltProcFuncs)

    //// doesn't work
    // switch value := getback.(type) {
    // case ImpltProcFuncs:
    //     fmt.Println("working", value)
    // }
}

type ImpltProcFuncs struct {
    Data string
}

func (p *ImpltProcFuncs) Init(
    ctx context.Context,
    stateGetter func() State,
    stateMutator func(mutateFunc func(State) State)) error {
    return nil
}
```

How can I have my `ImpltProcFuncs` back as a variable to get `Data`?

What am I missing?

I thought that Go were able to cast anything back from `interface`.

Comment: "i can't cast it back to the implementation" of course not as there _are_ _no_ casts in Go. Only type conversions and type assertions. And pointer-to-interface is basically never a good idea and it's a fundamental bad idea if you are not acustomed to the type system of Go.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

All right, after digging around, you can thank ChatGPT with Bing...

```
    if impl, ok := (*getback).(*ImpltProcFuncs); ok {
        fmt.Println("working", impl.Data)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("not working")
    }
```

When executed, it outputs "working get me back!!!!"

Comment: Alternative `func (c *Controller[T]) InterFuncs(pid string) (InterfaceFuncs[T], error)` (a pointer to an interface is [rarely useful](https://go.dev/doc/faq#pointer_to_interface))